# Saving Outlook mail attachment

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I want to save an .xlsx attachment from an email.

I am able to save the file but the extension is not by default .xlsx even though the email has an .xlsx attachment.

Even if I save it as ".xlsx"  `OutlookMail.Attachments.Item(1).SaveAsFile path & ".xlsx"` the file cannot be opened.

```
Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("WeeklyMail")
Dim path As String


path = "G:\" & Format(Date, "DD-MM-YYYY") & "-"
For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items        
    If OutlookMail.ReceivedTime >= Range("A1").Value Then
       title = OutlookMail.subject
       If InStr(title, "[Hello]") Then
            OutlookMail.Attachments.Item(1).SaveAsFile path
       End If
    End If
Next OutlookMail
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Helowxi, your path variable seems not to contain a file name at all:
Check out [https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-saveas-method-excel]
Add the file name you desire to your variable, e.g.

```
path = "G:\" & Format(Date, "DD-MM-YYYY") & "-MyFileName.xlsx"
```

and give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OutlookMail.Attachments.Item(1).FileName` to get the attachment's file name with extension

The code below will get the file extension and save.  I used instrrev as a precaution against a filename with two periods.

@EarlyBird2 is correct pointing out the missing filename

`Dim attchFileName as String`

`Dim myFileName as String`

`Dim FileExt as String`

`myFileName = "some file"`

`attchFileName = OutlookMail.Attachments.Item(1).FileName`

`FileExt = Right(attchFileName, len( attchFileName) - instrrev(attchFileName,"."))`

`OutlookMail.Attachments.Item(1).SaveAsFile path & "." &  myFileName & FileExt`